# BlToolkit insert data failure in BaseRepository class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, bltoolkit

I'm using BaseRepository in asp .Net MVC project. Edit operation works but in Add operation, I should make a trick to make it work. In detail, my base repository and BaseEntity classes:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity, T> : IRepository<TEntity, T> where TEntity : BaseEntity<T>
{
    private DbManager _context;

    private Table<TEntity> Table
    {
        get { return _context.GetTable<TEntity>(); }
    }

    public BaseRepository(DbManager context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //...

    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        //...

        return entity;
    }

    public TEntity Edit(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Update(entity);

        return entity;
    }

    //...
}

public class BaseEntity<T>
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public T Id { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried three ways for Add operation to make it work. First two ways gave errors.

**First way(Doesn't work):**

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Insert(entity);            

        return entity;
    }
```

*Error Message:*
`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '...' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

--

**Second way(Doesn't work):**

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Table.Insert(() => entity);          

        return entity;
    }
```

*Error Message:*
`Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

--

**Third way(Working):**

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        var l = new List<TEntity> { entity };
        _context.InsertBatch(l);            

        return entity;
    }
```

--

<del>Edit operation works without error, but for Add operation I need to make some trick. What is the problem with normal Add operation and, is there a way to make it work?</del>

I tried advice of @Mladen Macanović and I added `Identity` attribute to primary key in base BaseEntity class, *then errors shown above gone for entities having int type primary key*.

**Errors shown above gone for entities having int type of primary key:**

```
public class BaseEntity<T>
    {
        [PrimaryKey Identity]
        public T Id { get; set; }
    }
```

But, this is not a full solution because, **some of my entities have primary key in type of Guid**, so adding `Identity` attribute to them gives another error.

**InsertBatch method works without using Identity attribute.** So, you can add data without using Identity attribute in BaseEntity class for Identity column. What is the difference of insertbatch method? How can I resolve errors shown above without using `InsertBatch` method?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your database table. That is why you're getting the IDENTITY_INSERT error. Go to the SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the table, Design, and for the primary key column set the property Identity Specification -> (Is identity) to Yes.